# Save nsdate to disk

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar

I've looked at the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` function of `NSDate`. Can I use this function to store the interval to disk and then return it to `NSDate` with the same value as the original? I'm wary that the reference or interval could vary between machines and come up differently on another computer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

NSDate can be archived as an NSData instance and NSData can be easily written to / read from disk.

```
// Create and store it
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSData * dateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:date];
[dateData writeToFile:@"/Some/path/to/file.dat" atomically:NO];

// Now bring it back
NSData * restoredDateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Some/path/to/file.dat"];
NSDate * restoredDate = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:restoredDateData];
```

No error checking is done. Do better than that. ;-)

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver can also directly write to a file without NSData.

Comment: +archiveRootObject:toFile: - true.

Comment: Doesn't work, It says: -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Comment: Then what's wrong with the NSData instance you're handing it?

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me! I'm writing an app and I couldn't figure out for the life of me why my NSDate wasn't loading! =) Again, thank you so much! =)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want to store the result of `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` you can store it in an NSNumber as a double and then save that to disk using Joshua's NSKeyedArchiver method.

Comment: Or you could just write the 8 bytes of the double without bothering with archiving.